# Basic thing thats confusing me: How to access a variable created in a method from the main class

Tags: java

So my assignment for my course is relatively basic but I'm confused on a certain aspect. So the program creates a random arraylist of random size and random min and max values. That method is called listCreator(int a, int b, int c, int d).

```
    public ArrayList<Integer> listCreator(int lowRandGen, int upRandGen, int lowArraySize, int upArraySize){
     ArrayList numbers  = new ArrayList();

     int range = upArraySize-lowArraySize;
     int numberOfElements = (int) ((Math.random() * range) + lowArraySize);
     int range2 = upRandGen - lowRandGen;


     for(int i=1; i<=numberOfElements; i++){
         int listValue = (int) ((Math.random() * range2) + lowRandGen);
         numbers.add(listValue);

        }
     return numbers;
```

And then I created a method that would find a sequence in the code and return true if it is found. I also want to store the minimum value and maximum value that is in the created list using this method.  I'm not sure how I can create these variables (minVal and maxVal) and call them from the main.

```
    public boolean patternSearch(ArrayList<Integer> pattern){
      int cnt=0;
       int size = pattern.size();


    while(cnt<size){
   int cnt2 = 0;
   int value = (int)pattern.get(cnt2);
   int value2 = (int)pattern.get(cnt2+1);
   int value3= (int)pattern.get(cnt2+2);
   int value4 = (int)pattern.get(cnt2+3);
   int value5 = (int)pattern.get(cnt2+4);
   int maxVal=0;
   int minVal=0;

   if(value > maxVal){
       maxVal = value;

   }
   if(value<minVal){
      minVal= value;

   }

   if(isPrime(value) == true && (value2%2==0) && isPrime(value3) && value4%2==1 && isPrime(value5)) {
    return true;


       }
   cnt++;




   }

 return false;
```

}

Comment: You cannot gain access a variable declared in a method from outside that method. You can however declare it as a class-level variable and access it/initialize it in the method.

Comment: Can you show us the full Java _class_ which contains the above 2 methods?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a variable declared in a method from outside. You just *cannot*!

This is because when you declare a variable in a method i.e. a local variable, you are allocating some of the memory on the stack to store the variable. So consider this:

```
public void method () {
    //code 1
    int i;
    //code 2
}
```

When code 1 is executed, `i` does not exist (yet). So in code 1 you cannot use `i`. But in code 2, you can.

So you want to use `i` in another method? `i` might not be declared! Even if it *is* declared when you call the method, you cannot use it. It's kind of "private".

A workaround for this is to declare the variable in the *class*, outside the method. This way you can access the variable in any method in that class. If you went one step further you can declare the variable as `public`. Then THE WHOLE WORLD can use it! (**Not recommended**)